# Programatically stopping a servlet in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, war

I wish to stop/prevent the deployment of my WAR if certain properties are missing from my Properties file.

I have implemented a `ServletContextListener` class and in it's `contextInitialized` method, I need to be sure that a couple of properties are defined before any operations are carried out on my servlet.
In other words, I don't want Tomcat to deploy the WAR at all.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this advisable?

Comment: In a Simple case, at the Starting of Context Initialization, validates the property and throw Runtime Exception, that would stop your application get deployed (but not tomcat).

Comment: This worked fine, but is it recommended to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is. Unless your application needs some valid value from Properties file, it cannot perform its functionality properly. 

But, don't try to stop the tomcat server programmatically on failure case, that would rise some controversies on the User mind.

Finally, Don't forget to log the validation error message when you are throwing the exception.

Comment: I don't wish to stop Tomcat, just the servlet. Yes, I'm already logging the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use Spring Inject and the creation of a Bean failed, then the WAR will not be deployed.

Comment: I'm not using swing. Any method for simple Jersey Servlets?

Comment: I said Spring not Swing.

Comment: Typo. I meant Spring.

Comment: But Spring is very simple to add and Spring has no dependency on any application servers.
Spring also creates objects lazily which helps in developing light weight applications.

Comment: I'm aware of the advantages of Spring and I have already considered switching to the framework in the near future. Right now, I need the solution for a simple jersey servlet.

Comment: to use Spring you do not need to change Frameworks.  I am not talking about Spring MVC.  You can just use Spring for Bean Configuration.